# In the group $G=\langle r,s,t\mid r^2=s^3=t^3=rst\rangle,$ the element $rst$ has order $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Formally, if $F$ is the free group with basis $X = \{r, s, t\}$ and $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by $R = \{r^2 s^{-3}, s^3 t^{-3}, t^{3} (rst)^{-1}\}$, and $G = F/N$, I want to show that the coset of $rst$ has order $2$ in $G$. There are two parts to this: showing $rstrst = 1$ and showing $rst \neq 1$.

There must be some way to play with and combine the relations in just the right way to get $rstrst = 1$, but it seems difficult to get inverses to even appear in the right places and amounts to cancel all the $r, s, t$ of positive exponent. So far I know $r^2 = s^3 = t^3 = rst = str = trs$, $r = st$, $s^2 = tr$, $t^2 = rs$, and so I try at random some manipulations like $rstrst = t^2 s^2 r = (s^{-1}r)^2 (rt^{-1})^2 (t^2 s^{-1}) = \cdots$ or similar, which has just resulted in wandering about aimlessly.

On the other hand, to show $rst \neq 1$, I have previously shown that $G/\langle rst \rangle \cong A_4$, so I could exhibit a property that is different between $G$ and $A_4$ to say that $rst \neq 1$, but such a property might already rely on $rst$ being not $1$ to demonstrate, as the groups share all other defining relations. Proving $rst \neq 1$ directly by showing $rst \notin N$ in $F$ seems way too messy, since the elements of $N$ are words on the conjugates of $R$.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as I read group representations. It is $G=(generators\,|\, relations)$ where relations are words that equal $1$. So $rst=1$ because that is what you wrote in the title.

Comment: If we wish to write $G$ in that form, I have provided the set $R$ containing the words we are setting to equal $1$. In that form, $G = (r, s, t | R)$. From what I have seen, one can write $a = b$ as a relation meaning that $ab^{-1} \in R$.

Comment: If you meant $G=\langle r,s,t\,|\, r^2 s^{-3}, s^3 t^{-3}, t^{3} (rst)^{-1} \rangle$ so why didn't you write it? It makes no sense the way you did.

Comment: I have also given the set of relations $R$ explicitly (and described $G$ as the quotient of $F$ by the normal subgroup generated by $R$), if you prefer that form - but I believe the notation I have given is fair: as an example, the Wikipedia article for [Presentation of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) includes examples with relations $xy = yx$, $jij = i$, $z = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, etc. Many places (textbooks, other MathExchange questions, etc.) that I have seen groups with generators and relations, it is in this way.

Comment: Sure, but you did not explain the title within the title. It leaves guesswork to do. As it is written, the answer to the question in the title is: "Wrong, The order of rst equals one!" If you use uncommon syntax, then you have to explain it. Otherwise, use general syntax everybody can understand without decrypting the text.

Comment: The group given here is the [binary tetrahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tetrahedral_group), and by the link, this is the most common way to write its presentation. Both the title, and the linked article for this group, do not imply $rst$ is itself a relation.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm just used to read the words right to | as =1.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You are right. I try to calm my temper. Is there a chance to find the solution without identifying the group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cool problem, I enjoyed it. I found a completeley elementary proof by hand. Since $r = st$, I will work with the relations
$$
s^3 = t^3 = stst.
$$
From this, we may deduce that
$$
s^2 = tst, \quad \text{or} \quad t^{-1}s^2 = st. \quad (1)
$$
Similarly, we have
$$
t^2 = sts, \quad \text{or} \quad t^2s^{-1} = st, \quad \text{or} \quad t^2s^{-1}t^{-2} = st^{-1}. \quad (2)
$$
By applying $(1)$ three times, we may write that
\begin{align}
(stst)^2 &= s^3t^3 \\
 &= s^2(st)t^2 \\
 &= s^2t^{-1}s(st)t \\
 &= s(st^{-1})st^{-1}s(st) \\
 &= s\big(st^{-1})^2st^{-1}s^2 \\
 &= s\big(st^{-1}\big)^3s^2.
\end{align}
One may now notice that we are in the position to apply $(2)$, to obtain
\begin{align}
(stst)^2 &= s\big(t^2s^{-1}t^{-2}\big)^3s^2 \\
&= s\big(t^2s^{-3}t^{-2}\big)s^2 \\
&= st^2t^{-3}t^{-2}s^2 \\
&= st^{-3}s^2 \\
&= ss^{-3}s^2 \\
&= 1,
\end{align}
proving the first part completely by hand.

Next we show that $stst \neq 1$. We do this by considering the group homomorphism
$$
f : G \to \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)
$$
mapping
$$
s \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \text{and} \quad t \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
To check that this is a group homomorphism, by the universal property of the free group subject to relations, it suffices to verify that
$$
f(s)^3 = f(t)^3 = f(s)f(t)f(s)f(t).
$$
I will leave it to you to check that all of these expressions evaluate to $-I$, where $I$ denotes the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix over $\mathbb{F}_3$. Thus, we have now found a group homomorphism $f : G \to \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ under which the element $stst$ has non-trivial image, namely $-I$. Hence the element $stst$ cannot be trivial itself in $G$. Combining the two arguments above, we conclude that $stst$ must be of order precisely $2$.

Finally, I would like to remark that this argument circumvents having to show that $f$ is in fact an isomorphism; I wouldn't immediately see how to do that by hand but fortunately the above suffices for the problem in question.

Comment: Perfect! From this and $G/\langle rst \rangle \cong A_4$, we can conclude $|G|=24$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, may I ask what argument you used to show $G / \langle rst \rangle \cong A_4$?

Comment: We do, but $r = st$, so $rst = stst$

Comment: Ahh yes, I just saw. Very nice!

Comment: The translation matrix 1  1 // 0 1 has order 3, but both $s$ and $t$ have order 6. The negative the translation matrix then has order 6 too. The problem was symmetric enough in $s$ and $t$ that I hoped I could choose their images in a similar way; in this case, that meant I tried to transpose. I was then relieved to find that the identity involving $stst$ was also satisfied with these choices

Comment: Consider the surjective homomorphism $r \mapsto (1\;2)(3\;4), s \mapsto (1\;2\;3), t \mapsto (2\;3\;4)$. To show it is an isomorphism, I showed that $| G/\langle rst \rangle | \leq 18$, as then $A_4$ being a homomorphic image (quotient) would force $| G/\langle rst \rangle | = 12$. To do this, we may argue every element can be written as a word on $r, s$ with at most one $r$, and so $G/\langle rst \rangle = \{s^i r^j s^k \mid 0 \leq i < 3, 0 \leq j < 2, 0 \leq k < 3\}$.

Comment: (In fact, in the $j = 0$ case, we can fix $k = 0$ without loss of generality, since the $s$ powers would be adjacent, explicitly showing $|G/\langle rst \rangle| \leq 12$.)